# How to make a flip card responsive

Tags: html, css, flip

I have tried to create a flip card many times. I could create flip effect using preserve-3d property but it was not working in IE 11. I again searched web and tried to create flip effect. I could do it. The flip card  now works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11 but the final flip card is not responsive.

Here is the code:

```css
.card {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.card > div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 3s;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card > .front {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
.card:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.card > .back {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lime;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
.card:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.Card-Shadow {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px brown;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px brown;
  /* -webkit is vendor prefix referring to Chrome, Safari, and Opera browsers */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .back {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .front {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front Card-Shadow">Hello</div>
  <div class="back Card-Shadow">Thank You</div>
</div>
```

Could any one help in making it responsive?

Answer (score 0):

just min-width and small change in your card>div padding section and remove the media query .. because its auto responsive now. check it on IE 11.

```css
 

       .card {
        position: relative;
       }
    .card > div {
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      position: absolute;
      transition: transform 3s;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 20px 0px 20px 2px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .card > .front {

      background-color: green;
    }
    .card:hover .front {
      transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    .card > .back {

      background-color: lime;
      transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    }
    .card:hover .back {
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .Card-Shadow {
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px brown;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px brown;
      /* -webkit is vendor prefix referring to Chrome, Safari, and Opera browsers */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front Card-Shadow">Hello</div>
      <div class="back Card-Shadow">Thank You</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for useful tips!

But I have one question: How do changes in padding help in making the code responsive?

Comment: padding won't make it responsive. you padding-left the card div's with 20px. so its added the padding for both card with extra 20px of width. You can check it adding 20px again on your browser. And I just edit on your code just for make it responsive.